# Improving performance for calculations based on rolling covariance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Problem Statement**
I am working on implementing rolling portfolio optimization with pandas/numpy.  I have a pandas dataframe containing an assets daily returns, and other columns containing each assets respective risk weights.  I would like to compute the trailing n period covariance matrix and use that as an input to the optimizer at time t (including the risk weights column)

**Current Solution**
I have the current code:

```py
def cash_weights(rb: np.array, cov):
    cov = cov.to_numpy()
    rb = RiskBudgeting(cov, rb)
    rb.solve()
    return pd.Series(rb.x)

# datetime indexed df of prices, downloaded using yfinance
df = load_df()
df[ASSET_RETURNS] = df[TICKERS].pct_change()
df[TSMOM] = df[ASSET_RETURNS].shift(21).rolling("231D").apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1, raw=True)
df[RISK_WEIGHTS] = df[TSMOM].apply(lambda row: risk_weight(row), axis=1, result_type='expand', raw=True)
df[COVARIANCES] = df[ASSET_RETURNS].rolling(f"{look_back_period}D").cov().unstack()
df = df.dropna()
### This is the part that could use improvement.
df[CASH_WEIGHTS] = df[RISK_WEIGHTS + COVARIANCES].apply(lambda row: cash_weights(row), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.dropna()
```

The above solution works, using the [pyrb library](https://github.com/jcrichard/pyrb), which is written using numbas jit for performance.

Another approach I tried was `df[ASSET_RETURNS].rolling("60D").cov().dropna().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda covariance: cash_weights(risk_budget, covariance))`. (Note, this time i just used a single array, but hope to use another set of columns as input like the first snippet)  Both approaches work and have similar execution times.

I am aware that using `df.apply` or `df.groupby.apply` are not the most efficient way to compute these, as it's using python looping under the hood.  I have been reading about numpy vectorization, but I have not seen any examples of trying to vectorize computation on a rolling covariance matrix.  Another alternative could be explicit iteration.  I tried with vanilla for loops, but I'm missing how to do that efficiently with numpy.

Is what I am trying to do vectorizable with numpy? If not, how else could I optimize the speed of this computation?